# Remove rows from dataframe whose text does not contain items from a list

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, text

I am importing data from a table with inconsistent naming conventions. I have created a list of manufacturer names that I would like to use as a basis of comparison against the imported name. Ideally, I will delete all rows from the dataframe that do not align with the manufacturer list. I am trying to create an index vector using a for loop to iterate through each element of the dataframe column and compare against the list. If the text is there, update my index vector to true. If not, index vector is updated to false. Finally, I want to use the index vector to drop rows from the original data frame.

I have tried generators and sets, but to no avail. I thought a for loop would be less elegant but ultimately work, yet I'm still stuck.  My code is below.

- meltdat.Products is my dataframe column that contains the imported data
- mfgs is my list of manufacturer names
- prodex is my index vector

```
 meltdat = pd.DataFrame(
    {"Location":["S1","S1","S1","S1","S1"],
     "Date":["1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/1/2020", "1/1/2020"],
     "Products":['CC304RED','COHoney','EtainXL','Med467','MarysTop'],
     "Sold":[1,3,0,1,2]})

        mfgs = ['CC', 'Etain', 'Marys']

        for prods in meltdat.Products:
             if any(mfg in meltdat.Products[prods] for mfg in mfgs):
                  prodex[prods] = TRUE
             else:
                  prodex[prods] = FALSE
```

I added example data in the dataframe that mirrors my imported data.

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if we could see the data you're working with.

Comment: what is the datatype for your column `meltdat.Products`, can you share same example of products from your column `meltdat.Products` ?

Comment: Please provide the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) per the coding guidelines.  This *should* be a simple case of creating a new column based on existing ones.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll update the post with example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `pd.DataFrame.apply`:

```
meltdat[meltdat.Products.apply(lambda x: any(m in x for m in mfgs))]
```

Comment: Thank you. This yielded an error and mentioned 'm' was not identified. I'm not experienced in using lambda functions so maybe I did it incorrectly, but I copied the function as you described above.

Comment: This gave me exactly what I required. The dataframe rows were selected correctly. Thanks @kederrac.